# How to reset Xcode simulators?

Tags: swift, xcode, ios-simulator

I have deleted the Xcode simulators folder, because I was having some problems, restarted my Xcode and see this. Can someone explain me how to fix that, because I have duplicated simulators. Is it possible to fresh install all of them again?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**For iOS 14 and newer:**

```
Top Menu Bar > Device > Erase All Contents and Settings
```

**For iOS 11 and newer:**

```
Top Menu Bar > Hardware > Erase All Contents and Settings
```

**For previous versions:**

```
Top Menu Bar > Simulator > Reset Content and Settings
```

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the contents of the following folders -

- `/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes` - this folder contains all the simulators
- `~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator` - not strictly necessary to delete the contents of this folder, however since the OP wishes to fresh install the simulators again, this would help reclaim simulator related space.

Xcode may need to be restarted for those folder deletions to take effect.

After deleting the above folders, you can re-install the simulators by opening Xcode --> navigate to Preferences --> Components --> select whichever simulator version suits your needs.

[image]

If deleting the above mentioned folders doesn't work, try [uninstalling](https://macpaw.com/how-to/uninstall-xcode-on-macos) and re-installing Xcode from the Mac App Store.